# File for the path cannot be read with it contains Greek characters

Tags: java, file, path

the Issue that i am facing is that the files cannot be read, if stored in a tax box folder that contains greek characters.

we are taking file path as an input, whenever it contains greek Characters in the file path my code fails.

given error ......

java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: E:\strsWork_Dev\Î•Î¡Î§10017606

code is as follow,

```
   private void registerDirectory(Path path) throws IOException {

   WatchKey key = path.register(watchService, new WatchEvent.Kind[]{
            StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE
        }, SensitivityWatchEventModifier.HIGH);
        LOGGER.debug("registerDirectory adding path " + path.toString());
        keys.put(key, path);
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like an encoding problem.  You must end up with the correct characters.  Does it work when you hardcode the name in the source?

Comment: Yes it works when we hardcode the source and string not contain any greek Characters, so in the path variable, if it contains greek character it fails.

Comment: Are you familiar with https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ ?

Comment: Hi, Can anyone help me in solving this problem ?

Comment: Look into what exact bytes you have in your hand when you hardcode the string and when you pass it in. String.getBytes is your friend.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Sorry but didn't understand you. we have a function like   private void registerDirectory(Path path) throws IOException {

   WatchKey key = path.register(watchService, new WatchEvent.Kind[]{
            StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE
        }, SensitivityWatchEventModifier.HIGH);
        LOGGER.debug("registerDirectory adding path " + path.toString());
        keys.put(key, path);
    }

Comment: it gets file path from the location defined in the properties file and than processed 
the files based on the requirement. some time the file path it self contains the Greek characters 
and than my code fails. Can you please share some examples that i can use based on my function above
, basically we need to adjust the  path variable inside the function that if Greek characters 
come as part of the path variable it fails and gives error no such file Exception

Comment: You most likely have written your property file with the wrong encoding for Java to like it.  It _MUST_ be in UTF-8 and not some Windows code page. Do you understand what file encodings are?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen i recheck that and it is UTF-8 set for the property file and also for the overall project. i debug the code again.

Comment: traverseAndRegisterDirectories(Path path) {  try {Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {@Override
 public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException { registerDirectory(path);
return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE; }});} catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in traverseAndRegisterDirectories , restart the application to make sure that all folders are scanned correctly" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

Comment: it throw garbage in the path variable like C:\\folder01\\folder02\\d||a\u0087\ .......instead of Greek Character. when i come to the above method.